# What's the difference between the 3 "Apple Keynotes" podcasts?

Tags: itunes, podcasts

I want to download a keynote for offline viewing, but I'm not sure how to decide between the three different podcasts:

1. [Apple Keynotes](https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/apple-keynotes/id275834665?mt=2)
2. [Apple Keynotes (HD)](https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/apple-keynotes-hd/id470664050?mt=2)
3. [Apple Keynotes (1080p)](https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/apple-keynotes-1080p/id509310064?mt=2)

I'm assuming that HD and 1080p are higher quality, and therefore take more space. Which one is higher quality?

Answer (score 1):

In order of increasing quality & size: Regular, HD, 1080p.

[iMore forums](https://forums.imore.com/showthread.php?t=382824&s=8cc15ae7aa1c1df8f762f5c5eb3ab8ab&p=2884498&viewfull=1#post2884498):

> Normally when a video is referred to as HD. They are talking about
>   720p. Which is a slightly lower quality compared to 1080p and if they
>   say FHD (Full HD) they are talking about 1080p. I cant give you the
>   exact space you need to store the videos since they can vary in
>   length. But it could be over 1GB depending on the length.